# Whats missing in Adding Component to Page Layout

Tags: lightning-aura-components, trailhead

I am stuck in

Lightning Data Service Basics

Manipulate Records with force:recordData

[image]

I have added it like this

[image]

I can see both components in home page screen

[image]

Comment: did you save it and add it to the acocunt record home apge? maybe you can share your account raecord home page screen?

Comment: Yes I can see it on account home page screen

Comment: The wording in the challenge is confusing - I think it's asking you to add the components to the account RECORD home, not the Home tab. Your screenshots are showing the Home tab.

Comment: Updated now. Still getting the same error

Comment: Try deleting any other record pages on account, if there are others?